# Unable to start daemon process in android studio 1.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I am getting following error message while trying to create a new Android project. Can anybody help?

```
Gradle 'GPSTrack' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
22:38:35.626 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```